# Find the density function of X given the joint density distribution X and Y

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

Given the joint density function f of X and Y, find the density of X:
$$
f(x, y) = 
     \begin{cases}
       xe^{-x + y} &\quad x>0, y>0 \\
       0, &\quad \text{otherwise}
     \end{cases}
$$

My approach to computing the marginal is the following:
$$
f_X = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x, y) dy = 
    \begin{cases}
        \int_0^{\infty} f(x, y) dy  = xe^{-x}\int_0^{\infty} e^y dy = \infty \textbf{???!!!}, &\quad x > 0 \\
        0, &\quad \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
$$

My problem is that the pdf goes to $\infty$ if x>0. Am I correctly computing the pdf and the integral, or am I missing something?

Comment: There must be a mistrake in your formula, since $f(x,y)$ cannot be a density function, since its double integral isn't 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the joint density should have been $$
f(x, y) = 
     \begin{cases}
       xe^{-(x + y)} &\quad x>0, y>0 \\
       0, &\quad \text{otherwise}
     \end{cases}
$$
since this integrates to $1$, i.e. the author probably forgot the parentheses.

Your approach to computing the marginal density w.r.t. $X$ is fine.